# What is the fastest way to access the coordinates of nodes in Abaqus v6.12 using python scripting?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a faster way to access the coordinates of a lot (300,000) of nodes in abaqus 6.12 using python scripting?
Currently I do the following:

```
NodeArraySet=dbi.nodeSets['Nodeset1'].nodes #dbi is the database instance
for k in range(len(NodeArraySet)):
    Coordinates[k] = NodeArraySet[k].coordinates
#Do stuff with coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to generate the input file and scrape the node definitions from the text.